# how to know which component is currently focused in flex

Tags: apache, apache-flex, adobe, flex4

I Want to know which component currently being focused in flex. I have text field and combobox when moving the focus from one component to another i want print the id of the particular component

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by
`var ComponentWithFocus : IFocusManagerComponent= FocusManager.getFocus();`